# Uislider with Avplayer

Tags: ios

Hi i created Avplayer for playing audio from server and its working perfectly but UISlider is not syncing with Audio even after updating UISlider method but the slider is moving properly but its not syncing with audio.i need to match that audio with UISlider

```
seekbar =[[UISlider alloc]init];
    seekbar.frame=CGRectMake(10,CGRectGetMinY(PlayAudio.frame)-50, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)-20, 20);
   [seekbar addTarget:self action:@selector(seektime:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    seekbar.continuous=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:seekbar];
-(void)Audio{
    NSString *urlString= @"https:/embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/85dcf8de9db3830f47f136a4dba89114be58403f/dhwpxq4l9l.wav";

    audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[audioPlayer currentItem]];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [audioPlayer play];
    NSLog(@"Audio playing");
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == audioPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");

        } else if (audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
            [audioPlayer play];


        } else if (audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");

        }
    }
}


- (void)seektime:(UISlider*)sender {
   CGFloat currentSongTime = CMTimeGetSeconds([audioPlayer currentTime]);
    seekbar.value = currentSongTime;

    seekbar.minimumValue=0;
    seekbar.maximumValue=currentSongTime;
}

- (void)updateProgress {

    [seekbar setValue:CMTimeGetSeconds(audioPlayer.currentTime)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you changing the maximum value at every change?
You can set the `minimumValue` and `maximumValue` when you get AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay according to `audioPlayer.currentItem.duration`

So instead of the `seektime` you can just use:

```
    else if (audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
                NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
                [audioPlayer play];
                seekbar.minimumValue = 0;
                seekbar.maximumValue = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioPlayer.currentItem.duration);

    }
```

Comment: You cant set a maximum value like this.i am struck up with that only.

Comment: What do you mean you can't? You can set a maximum value for UISlider and when the player is ready to play you have the duration of the audio.

Comment: Yeah Exactly my slider moving to end when i start playing @Adam

Comment: That's because you are setting the seekbar value to be equal to the maximum value. Just set the time as I wrote and remove the entire `seektime`  function.

Comment: I did that but still its not working the problem on this line **seekbar.maximumValue = audioPlayer.currentItem.duration;**

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. Was missing `CMTimeGetSeconds`